# Is it possible to launch an Instant App based on location?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm wondering if you can launch a given Instant App based on the user's location. Is this kind of thing possible? I suppose it would require some kind of server to be always running on the device.

Edit: To clarify a bit, this would be like if App A has a service that tracks the user's location and if they go to a certain spot it would launch Instant App B.

Thanks!

Comment: No, instant-apps are meant to be launched via URLs, not from a regular installed app.

Answer (score 0):

it would need a constant running service and launching the app might be a problem since this particular function could be ransomware like but a notification could be instead that's.
beside that it would a continuous location request at all time.